# Uniqueness of probability densities given integral identity

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

Let $p$ and $q$ be two probability density functions, consider the identity:

$$
\int \left[\log(p(x))\right]p(x)dx = \int \left[\log(p(x))\right]q(x)dx. \qquad(*)
$$

Assuming both integrals exist, under what conditions can we conclude that identity $(*)$ implies that $p$ and $q$ are identical?

Some thoughts: if $p$ is the uniform i.e. $p(x)=c$ over some bounded set, then the $(*)$ is true for all $p$ and $q$. But I think that is the only case.

Comment: The most you can hope for is a.e. equivalence, (just small point).

Comment: Are these integrals indefinite integrals?  If so, just take derivatives.

Comment: The integrals are definite over the support of the $p$ and $q$.